# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am reading the book.'spring in action'.I use `JNDI` to config my `DataSouce`.

And I use Java-based to Config my project.

But I met this Exception.I searched many answers,But could not solve my problem.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcSpitterRepository' defined in file [D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\spitter\data\JdbcSpitterRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [spitter/config/DataConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: Factory method 'jdbcTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [spitter/config/DataConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: Factory method 'jdbcTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5194)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [spitter/config/DataConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: Factory method 'jdbcTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: Factory method 'jdbcTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:168)
    at spitter.config.DataConfig.jdbcTemplate(DataConfig.java:32)
    at spitter.config.DataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d3ba49d.CGLIB$jdbcTemplate$1(<generated>)
    at spitter.config.DataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d3ba49d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9d6b63b2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355)
    at spitter.config.DataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d3ba49d.jdbcTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 72 more
```

But I really define the `JdbcTemplate` and `datasource` in My config.

SpitterWebInitializer

```
public class SpitterWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {
            WebConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("D:\\temp"));
    }
}
```

RootConfig

```
@Configuration
@Import(DataConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "spitter",
        excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,value = EnableWebMvc.class)
})
public class RootConfig {
}
```

DataConfig

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("schema.sql")
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

}
```

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"spitter.web","spitter.data"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        return viewResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource(){
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }


}
```

JdbcSpitterRepository

```
@Repository
public class JdbcSpitterRepository implements SpittleRepository {


    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final String INSERT_SPITTER = "insert into Spitter (username, password, fullname, email, updateByEmail) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static final String SELECT_SPITTER = "select id, username, password, fullname, email from Spitter";

    @Autowired
    public JdbcSpitterRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Spittle> findSpittles(long max, int count) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Spittle findOne(long spittleId) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_SPITTER,
                spitter.getUsername(),
                spitter.getPassword(),
                spitter.getFullName(),
                spitter.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveSpittle(Spittle spittle) {

    }

    @Override
    public Spitter findByUsername(String username) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spitter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

And I use tomcat 9.0.

server.xml

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

    <Resource name="jdbc/SpittrDS"
      global="jdbc/SpittrDS"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpittrDS"
      username="root"
      password=" "
      maxActive="100"
      maxIdle="20"
      minIdle="5"
      maxWait="10000"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/SpittrDS"
                global="jdbc/SpittrDS"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

http://7xrsib.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/QQ%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%9620160412210627.jpg

you can see the whole project on[github](https://github.com/threezj/LearnSpring/tree/master/Spitter)

Comment: Where is the Spring package scan config?

Comment: @ComponentScan({"spitter.web","spitter.data"})

Comment: And the declaration to scan for the package which contains this annotattion?

Comment: the `WebConfig` class which extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: Show your web.xml or class that extends WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: Are you sure the DataSource is correct? Is it instantiated by Spring?

Comment: The problem is your `jdbctemplate` bean is not reachable by another context, and I just cannot see which context your `JdbcSpitterRepository` is. Another alternative is to move your `jdbctemplate` to `RootConfig` .

Comment: Your `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` as well as the Repository should be in the `RootCOnfig`. Also your `JdbcSpitterRepository` and I suspect that in your `RootConfig` you have a `@ComponentScan` creating another instance of the repo, however as the datasource and template are defined in a child context, those are inaccessible from the root context. Hence the error.

Comment: I moved the `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate ` to the RootConfig.still have some exception.I am new to Spring.please help me.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are scanning the same packages twice resulting in  multiple creation of your beans . First in the `RootConfig.class` which is the main `applicationContext`

(`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "spitter",
        excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,value = EnableWebMvc.class)
})`)

and another scan on the `servletContext` class `WebConfig.class`;

```
@ComponentScan({"spitter.web","spitter.data"})
```

You should seperate your application Config from your webconfig, do the scan this way :

**Root**:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "spitter.Data")
```

**WebConfig**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "spitter.web")
```

and Change the `JdbcTemplace` config from :

```
@Bean
  public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
```

to

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}
```

Comment: I did the Change.but same problem.`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required`.I debug to the line.I find the `datasouce` is null

Comment: from what package you got that datasource ?

Comment: in the `config` package, `dataconfig` class

Comment: you can see the whole project on[github](https://github.com/threezj/LearnSpring/tree/master/Spitter)

Comment: Could you please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465272/caused-by-javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-jdbc-baeldungdatabase-is-n

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `datasource` `bean` code.

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/SpittrDS");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: So you problem just wrong datasource, I though you are using the right datasource. Ok then, I'm just sit here and laugh. hehe..